# Java String#split() - Creates memory leak

Tags: java, memory-management

Can not understand how `split` method of `java.lang.String` can cause memory leak?
Example -

```
private boolean isValidHostName(String hostName)
{
    ValidationHandler handler = ValidationHandler.INSTANCE;
    boolean isValid =
            hostName != null && (hostName.toLowerCase(ENGLISH).startsWith("ws://") || hostName
                    .toLowerCase(ENGLISH).startsWith("wss://"));
    if (isValid)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("null")
        String[] splits = hostName.split("//");
        if (splits.length == 2)
        {
            if (splits[1].indexOf(":") != -1)
            {
                splits = splits[1].split(":");
                try
                {
                    int portNum = Integer.parseInt(splits[1]);
                    isValid = (handler.validateIpAddress(splits[0]) || handler
                            .validateDomain(splits[0], false)) && (portNum >= 0
                            && portNum <= 65535);
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    isValid = false;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                isValid = handler.validateIpAddress(splits[1]) || handler
                        .validateDomain(splits[1], false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
    if (!isValid)
    {
        errorStrBuilder.append("\nInvalid hostname specified.");
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

And how to fix that problem?

Few are asking clarity on question, so in short -

1. Can String#split() cause memory leak?
2. If yes? then how to solve hat? specifically in the above example.

Comment: Why do you say it causes a memory leak? Maybe it's just me not following, but I'd like to have more information so I can understand your question.

Comment: tried to find out on internet, could not find any discussion on String#split(). Everyone talk about String#subString()

Comment: I am using Parasoft for code analysis, it is giving error like - The 'split()' method is known to cause memory leaks. Inspect its usage to make sure memory leaks are not possible in this case

Comment: This sounds like an error in your code analysis tool. The code you have posted above will not cause a memory leak. "Inspect its usage to make sure memory leaks are not possible in this case" implies that `String.split()` can sometimes cause memory leaks, but sometimes it is fine. This is a case where it is fine.

Comment: I mean, if there was no coincidence of your character in the string, I guess using the split method might behave weird and that's maybe where this is coming from. But in your particular case I don't see any memory leak issue.

Comment: Actual code is this, can not understand where it is causing memory leak

Comment: @JineshFrancis What is your reason for that entirely counterproductive recommendation?

Comment: @user207421 The string[] splits is created locally and it is passing to some other functions/class.When the GC tries to destroy the instance of current class and it's members it can't destroys it becase it is referering some other place.

Comment: @user207421 Is that making sense?

Comment: @JineshFrancis I don’t know what you’ve suggested, but what you’ve written in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58706175/java-stringsplit-creates-memory-leak#comment103712038_58706175), is an obsolete consideration.  The garbage collector will reclaim unused objects. Objects still in use, regardless of whether by the “instance of current class” or “some other place”, are not reclaimed, because they are in use. So it doesn’t matter where an object was created or were an object is still used, unused object are reclaimed and objects still in use are kept and that’s fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never come across claims of `split()` itself causing memory leaks.

If they're referring to `substring()` referring the original `char[]` (as `split()` uses `substring` internally), that was changed in [Java 7u6](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-May/010257.html), so unless you're running on legacy java, that shouldn't be an issue either.

Comment: Seems like that, so another case of an analysis tool spreading old myths. The funniest part of it is the suggested solution, to analyze the code. What’s the worth of an analysis tool that simply searches for the occurrence of a method call, to suggest to do the real analysis manually…